Walking someone out 4 amos
The Chofetz Chaim in Ahavas Chesed Chelek Gimmel Chapter Beis talks about the importance and the Mitzvah to escort a guest, the Chofetz Chaim gives several opinions as to how far one must escort, for the opinion that holds "4 amos", from where does one begin to count this distance? From one’s front door? Or if one has a long front yard (for example), must one escort the guest at least four Amos out of the property line?

According to this theory, it could be 4 amos from anywhere.
